# Forcing a sealed class

Tags: c#, sealed

Is it possible in C# to force a sealed class through an interface or wildcard? For example something like:

```
public interface A<SealedItem> where SealedItem : sealed
```

or maybe something like:

```
public sealed interface A {}
public class B : A // B is now sealed.
```

This may sound weird but I would like to "force" a sealed instance for conventions shake. Does something like this exists?

Extra context: I have request objects that are exposed through an API. I only use the request object for "reading" the data. These request objects may change over time, however, I don't want these request objects to influence each other. Using inheritance in my request objects can cause "problems". So "forcing" a sealed class would be nice in my case I guess.

Why Inheritance can be bad in my situation: Let's say I have the following requests:

```
public class RequestA { public int Number { get; set; } }
public class RequestB : RequestA { public int Id { get; set; } }
```

Both requests use the value number in this example. Let's say the implementation of RequestA changes and it doesn't need the `number` value anymore. My code for request B will now break (just a small example). Another example is when RequestA gets a new property that is not used by Request B. I now have an unused property in the logic for my RequestB.

Comment: `This may sound weird` yes... yes indeed it does. i think you need to rethink your design

Comment: Why exactly would you want this? If there's any case where this would be useful, then inheritance wouldn't be inheritance but some weird stuff

Comment: why? where's the point in preventing implementers from using inheritance? do you have a use case where this makes sense?

Comment: Closest you can get is to force `SealedItem` to be a struct (which can't be inherited from): `public interface A<SealedItem> where SealedItem : struct` - but that's probably not going to be much help.

Comment: One approach is to create a unit test that will scan your project and check if class is inherited somewhere. To be honest I don't see anything bad in inheritance but to each their own

Comment: I added some examples why inheritance might be "bad" in my example.

Comment: Hmm. Old question, I know, but I ended up here because I have a specific scenario that can serve as an example. Suppose we have some kind of Hanlder (CQRS, but it's beside the point). Should a Handler for some situation be inherited? Definitely not. What if we have a considerably large application with many devs working on it? Wouldn't it be a good idea to be able to restrict implementations somehow? I think so. The only way I can think of to do this is through reflection, by implementing logic that scans my assemblies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The fact that the class is `sealed` simply means it can't be inherited.

> For example something like: `public interface A<SealedItem> where SealedItem : sealed`

You can only use generic constraints for things that controls how a type can be used - if it's a class or a struct, if it implements an interface or is derived from a specific type or if it has a public constructor that takes no parameters.

> or maybe something like: `public sealed interface A {}`

An interface can't be marked as `sealed`.

The one thing that you can do to prevent inheritance is to use value types - structs can't inherit from anything other than the `ValueType` special class (and that's beyond your control), nor can the be inherited from -
from [Structs (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs):

> A struct cannot inherit from another struct or class, and it cannot be the base of a class.

however this will probably not be a good choice in most cases, especially if you need reference type semantics in your code (and in most cases, you do).

**Update** - followed by an update to the question:

> Extra context: I have request objects that are exposed through an API. These request objects may change over time, however, I don't want these request objects to influence each other.

You can create all your request classes as sealed - and leave comments in the code for future developments that requests should be sealed and explain why - but that's probably all you can do, other than using structs instead of classes (which might not be a bad idea, if it's only for API requests.)

Check out [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) to see if your requests meets the guidelines:

> **✓ CONSIDER** defining a struct instead of a class if instances of the type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in other objects.
>
> **X AVOID** defining a struct unless the type has all of the following characteristics:
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (int, double, etc.).
> - It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.
>
> In all other cases, you should define your types as classes.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to mark a `.class interface sealed` on IL level - no practical use though, and probably resulting in an ill-formed program.

Comment: My request objects only contain properties and I only use them for "reading". So a struct might be a valid option?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a link to Microsoft Docs page called `Choosing Between Class and Struct` - I believe that should answer your question

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.

Btw, you don't **inherit** interfaces, you **implement** interfaces, i.e. yo just provide implementation to empty methods.